# Android Wear and network requests

Tags: android, wear-os

As far as I know, Android Wear does not allow us to make network requests without going through the smartphone.

After updating to Android Wear 5.1.1, the watch can now connect directly to the WiFi.
So, I was wondering if it is now possible to use this connection to make network requests.

Thanks

Comment: you could try and see what happens ?

Comment: I will try for sure! I was just wondering if someone already tried and share his knowledge.